# A problem of Permutations and combinations

Tags: permutations, combinations

8 points are lying in a plane if 4 points out of these 8 points are collinear (lying on a line) then how many distinct quadrilaterals can be made using these 8 points???
I am not able to understand anything here can anyone please explain this questions answer in detail.

Comment: To make a quadrilateral, we need 4 points. However, it is necessary that these out of these four points, no three are collinear. Does that help?

Comment: Nope!! I had arrived at this result but still four points are needed to be joined in which I am having lot of trouble a line is fine because only two points are to be joined but here its a different story...

Comment: @Gummy, if one point is inside a triangle formed by three other points, then 3 different quadrilaterals can be made from those four points.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Aha..... Seems to be correct.... Guess I'll delete my comment. Although I'm pretty sure we're not to take that into account...?

Comment: Yes I was also thinking that the answer which was given in my book 53 (that is) was maximum or maybe minimum no of quadrilaterals that can be formed. Also I was thinking how can we get an answer independent of the points positions.there must be something else also ?? But there wasn't !!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Abridged and revised answer considering only convex quadrilaterals:*

The disposition of the 4 collinear points and the 4 "solo" points must be such as to allow only convex quadrilaterals (no point must be inside the triangle formed by the other 3 chosen points)

*No point from collinear group and 4 from solo group*: $\binom40\binom44 = 1$ quadrilateral.

*1 point from collinear group and 3 from solo group* $\binom41\binom43 = 16$ quadrilaterals

*2 points from collinear group and 2 from solo group:* $\binom42\binom42$ = 36 quadrilaterals

We can't take more than 2 points from the collinear group, thus

Number of convex quadrilaterals possible = **1+16+36 = 53**

Comment: That means the question should have asked for the number of convex quadrilaterals ???

Comment: As I have said, the conditions are apparently that (i) quadrilaterals are convex (ii)  the 4 "solo" points are on one side of the line formed by the 4 collinear points. I have counted such convex quadrilaterals to be 53. From any 4 non-collinear points, only **one** convex quadrilateral can be formed, that is why 1+16+36 = 53

Comment: That is one more condition!! All The 4 solo points are only on one side of the line. But still does this disqualify the existence of the one case that I have written in my earlier comments

Comment: Yeah!! Not said you didn't!! But you still didn't answer  the solo case which is troubling me can it exist!!

Comment: Basically in permutation/combination we are randomly selecting and joining points while forming the quadrilateral so can it not happen that while trying to join four points it "may happen" a side or line intersects another line which we had made Earlier because of which in this case –

Comment: also we will have four points connected we will also have four lines out of which one "may"intersect the other so even though we have made and joined four points/lines it will still not be a quadrilateral as in a quadrilateral the sides do not intersect each other!! But we are not even talking about such a case here !! after all your solution is based on randomly connecting four points and making sure that the points are not in a line and no quadrilateral is counted again

Comment: So does the second condition --4 solo points on one side of the line disqualify the existence of the case I have talked about.

Comment: Although "intersecting quadrilaterals" can always be avoided, I have edited the precise conditions for getting only convex quadrilaterals in the answer.

Comment: Can you please explain your this statement// " No point from 4 collinear: 33
1 point from 4 collinear: (41)(43)⋅3=48......." A little bit more??

Comment: e.g. 1 point from 4 collinear = $\binom41$, balance 3 points from "solo" points = $\binom43$ etc. But all that was superseded. I am abridging my answer to consider only convex quadrilaterals.

Comment: OK !! Done Thnx but what if I was asked the total number of quadrilaterals that can be formed that is taking all three cases -convex,concave and intersecting quadrilaterals how should I proccede then ?? I noticed that you had answered it in your earlier answer but now you removed it so in this question(taking all cases) would the answer have been 72

Comment: Also can you please add that part,it was good actually after all proving the question wrong in a way is not an easy task!!

Comment: Much more than 72. Wikipedia classifies quadrilaterals as *simple* (*convex* or *concave*)  and *complex* (*self-intersecting/crossed*). Simply allowing crossed types raises the tally to 104. Also, each pattern of points in the form of a triangle with the 4th point inside, gives rise to **3** concave quadrilaterals, although due to the disposition of the points, all combos may not permit concave quadrilaterals.

Comment: The type of formation you mentioned for four points "pattern of points in the form of a triangle with the 4th point inside, gives rise to 3 concave quadrilaterals"so if one asks that if 4 points are non-collinear then the number of convex quadrilaterals that can be formed are--?? So what should be the answer??

Comment: As with the formation you mentioned no convex quadrilateral will be formed so that means that this question is actually dependent on the position of the point and that If four points(non collinear) are given we can't say how many quadrilaterals of each type will be formed

Comment: Commonly, we would say that 1 convex quadrilateral can be formed given 4 non collinear points, but to be precise, this is true if and only if none of the points is inside the triangle formed by any 3 of the other points, i.e the disposition of the points is not such that it leads to formation of concave quadrilaterals.  And if the disposition of the points does lead to formation of concave quadrilaterals, mo convex quadrilateral can be formed with those 4 points.